# Assigning Row-Fluid every Three Span4 in PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I'm currently building a WordPress theme that is based off Roots Theme and Twitter Bootstrap, but I came accross a problem.

I want to assign each widget span4 with row-fluid, but how do I generate row-fluid every 3 sections / widgets?

```
<?php
function roots_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('Footer', 'roots'),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-footer',
        'before_widget' => '<section class="widget span4 %1$s %2$s"><div class="widget-inner">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div></section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3>',
       'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ));
}
?>
```

Is there any way to do this in PHP?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Opps, just found out WordPress's register_sidebar() function only runs through once, so count looping won't work.